# "ArrayOf..." simpleWsdl WCF

Tags: wcf

I am creating WCF to communicate with SAP and have to send arrays of different objects.
Here is an example of DataContracts

```
[DataContract] 
public class MesPet12
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Shifts")]
    public ShiftMes[] Shifts { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(Name = "Shift")]
public class ShiftMes
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public Order[] Orders { get; set; }
}
```

In singleWsd there is the following:

```
<xs:complexType name="MesPet12">
   <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Date" type="xs:dateTime"/>
     <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Shifts" type="tns:ArrayOfShiftMes"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfShiftMes">
<xs:sequence>
   <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="ShiftMes" nillable="true" 
    type="tns:ShiftMes"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="ShiftMes">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Id" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Orders" type="tns:ArrayOfOrder"/>
   </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

As you can see the new ComplexType "ArrayOfShiftMes" was generated. Everythings works fine, but as I know SAP doesn't like something like "ArrayOf...".

How can I either avoid creating extra complex type "ArrayOf" or rename it?

Comment: Have you tried it with `List<ShiftMes>`?

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't help.. I still have "ArrayOf.."

Answer (score 0):

If somebody face with the same issue, the solution is the following:
you just need to add the attribute

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Shifts", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public ShiftMes[] Shifts { get; set; }
```